# Login loop in WebForms started after updating to .NET 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We are now building web apps using MVC, but have a number of legacy WebForm apps on a Server 2008 R2 box that we are updating from 4.5 to 4.6.1 and moving to server 2016..

Most follow the same format that everything in the Secure directory requires authentication and is redirected to the login page - so far they have all worked, but one app is throwing a loop (HTTP Error 404.15 - Query string too long) and I can't even access the login page directly...

Web.config in the Secure directory

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SessionWarning" value ="18"/>
  </appSettings>
  <location path="">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Same format as the ones that work. The main Web.Config contains

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="SecureForms" loginUrl="Secure/Login"/>
</authentication>
```

This one has me totally baffled - I have no idea why it's throwing the toys out when others work flawlessly!

Thanks

Comment: Check IIS W3C logs and look for very long query strings around the time you experience the error.

Comment: Turns out there was no form with the ID 'SecureForms' - added that and got to the login page - now it won't authenticate - sigh!